Base Abstract class exposing virtual function that Childs overrides with different number of arguments
I have some classes:
class Transform {
    public:
    virtual auto operator()() const -> void = 0;
};

class FourierTransform : public Transform{
    public:
    virtual auto operator()(type1&, type2&) const -> void = 0; // someone else will override with a real operation
};

class DWTTransform : public Transform{
    public:
    auto operator()(type3&, type4&, type5&, type6&) const;
};

I want to be able to have a pointer to the base and be able to use a operation at runtime depending on which class I use, like this:
shared_ptr<Transform>fft = make_shared<IterativeFastFourierTransform>();
fft->operator()(stuff1, stuff2);


No, can't do. To override a function, the parameters must match - both in number and types.

Different number or types of arguments is not overriding.

Sure, i understand this is not the correct pattern to use in order to achieve this, this is just te best approximation I could come up with, I am more than welcome to explore other solutions

I updated the code removing the everything is ok, my idea was to put something there to indicate that each child could override the function with whatever they wanted

If the call needs a different amount of parameters for Fourier vs. DWT, how would you call it? Normally, when using base classes and virtual member functions, the call site would not know, which derived class it is dealing with. Possible solutions: a) The classes are set up before and just the execution happens now without parameters; b) The parameters are put into a parameter class, which can hold either set of parameters (either directly or also with inheritance; think of vector of parameters). c) You abstract also the parameters in a way that the number of parameters is the same.

Indeed, what would be the point of the common ancestor here?

All in all for abstraction you have to draw a line, what code needs to know; you have not fully drawn that line so far.

@Sebastian They idea was to have the abstraction of transformation, that taken as input my signal would then represent in its preffered way applying their own transformations, the caller would only know that such transformation has happened and maybe the possibility to discard a certain percentage of the information from the internal representation and then goinf back to the original input space after applying such compression and/or manipulations. I hope to have been clear

Not fully. But if the caller does not know, you also have to abstract the parameters, e.g. with a class hierarchy that hold input data and another for output and those would be the parameters for the function. So both derived transforms would have the same base input and base output parameters.

On a side note: fft->operator()(stuff1, stuff2); can be simplified to (*fft)(stuff1, stuff2); instead. Let the compiler call operators for you, don't call them directly unless you REALLY need to (and that is not required in this case).

One more option would be to call the operator() from a templated function. The templated function can be defined with an arbitrary number of parameters, which it forwards.
See the examples for make_unique2 and make_B on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward

"Overriding" exists so users can call a function on the base class, without knowing what the actual class is. The classic example is a virtual void print() const =0; function that outputs the object, regardless of what the actual class is.
In C++ terminology, that requires that the parameters to the functions match. Which is also the only reasonable thing -- how would someone know what parameters to pass to your Transform->operator()() if it doesn't know what the class is?
In your case, the caller needs to know the class anyway, so it can provide the required parameters. Thus, it's not overriding anything, it's just implementing functions with a similar name and whatever parameters are needed for that particular class.
Thus, this is really just a
class Transform {
};

class FourierTransform : public Transform{
    public:
    whatever operator()(type1&, type2&) const;
};

class DWTTransform : public Transform{
    public:
    whatever operator()(type3&, type4&, type5&, type6&) const;
};

because all these operator() are completely unrelated anyway.
